# Wix domain to shopify

Tags: dns, ip-address, shopify

I am trying to transfer a wix domain to a shopify. Apparently Shopify does not accept transered domains which is kinda lame. So I attempted to follow these steps from this site: https://www.wix.com/support/html5/domains/managing-your-domain-records/kb/how-to-add-dns-records-1

and change the DNS for the domain to the shopify IP Address but that didn't work, does anyone have any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your registrar site where you will manage your dns records for your domain. Remove the ones pointing to wix. Add the CNAME pointing to yourstore.myshopify.com and add the A record IP address which Shopify gives you. Let the propagation occur (it can take up to 72 hours) and you're good to go.

Comment: Hey so I changed the CNAME and it came out as yourstore.myshopify.com.yourstore.com is that okay? Will whats on my shopify page yourstore.shopify to display on my wix domain yourstore.com?

Comment: I sent you an email. Thank you in advanced for helping